# CSS slideshow with 2 image div not working correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a CSS slideshow which is displaying differently in Firefox and Chrome. What is notable about the CSS is that one "figure" is a div containing two images - while the first figure is a simple image, the second figure is a div containing a background image and a smaller image to be overlaid onto it.

In Firefox 57 the slideshow displays "correctly", as I intended.  But in Chrome 62 upon initial display the overlay image appears atop the first slide - whereas it should only appear atop the second slide.  But this happens only on the initial display (or when re-loaded) - thereafter, as the slideshow repeats, the first slide appears as it should, without the overlay image.

I have a stripped-down working JSfiddle example at https://jsfiddle.net/glendeni/uwb13z87/
(note that it behaves ala Chrome, not ala Firefox)

I believe the crux is in the following CSS

```
#figure-container { position: relative; }
#top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

with the second figure HTML

```
<figure>
   <div id="figure-container">
     <img class="center" src="second_slide.jpg">
     <img id="top" src="second_slide_overlay.png">
   </div>
 </figure>
```

I would like to know if there is some CSS or Javascript I can add which would prevent Chrome from initially displaying the overlay image, since the current behavior is going to prevent me from using the overlay image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index on the overlay is causing it to display above both the first and second slides. However, you only see it above the first slide on the first run, because after the 2 second delay, the animation starts, and sets its opacity to zero on the next time.

You can fix this by setting an even higher z-index on your first slide, like so:

```
.css-slideshow-header figure:nth-child(2) { 
  animation: xfade 4s 0s infinite; 
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: PS: I think another fix would be to set z-index:0 on all the figure:nth-child entries, in case I move the order of the images later (since in the un-stripped-down version there are 6 figures)